# Imperative with the first person using やってみなさい

Tags: grammar

> 抑えてるに決まってるでしょ！周りの役者は揃いも揃って大根役者ばっかり！！メインキャストの中でマトモに演技出来るの私だけなのよ！！**こん中で私がバリバリやってみなさい！** 他の役者の大根ぶりが浮き彫りになっちゃってぶり大根でしょ！！

Is this a first-person imperative sentence? What does it mean? Is there something omitted?

The English translation is:

> Just imagine if I gave it my all in that situation!

The idea I have is this:

こん中で: In here

私が: Meaning "I" is the subject

バリバリ: Adverb meaning vigorously

やってみなさい: Verb try doing in imperative

Comment: Duplicate? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/86254/45489